# pointwise operations on scipy.sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it possible to apply for example `numpy.exp` or similar pointwise operators to all elements in a `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` or another sparse matrix format?

```
import numpy
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

x = numpy.ones((10,10))
y = numpy.exp(x)

x = lil_matrix(numpy.ones((10,10)))
# y = ????
```

`numpy.exp(x)` or `scipy.exp(x)` yields an `AttributeError`, and `numpy.exp(x.data)` yields the same.

thanks!

Comment: I think that presently this isn't made to work in any of the sparse matrix formats. Personally, I think that separate sparse functions should be made rather than slowing down the regular ones. The workaround, as shown by Olivier, is to convert to basically any other sparse format and work on the `data` attribute. The data attribute of the lil matrices doesn't work for this because it is an array of type object.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the full details, but converting to another type works, at least when using the array of non zero elements:

```
xcsc = x.tocsc()
numpy.exp(xcsc.data) # works
```

Comment: Yes.  As it says in the docs http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html the lil format is mainly intended to be used as a method for building sparse arrays not performing operations.  The docs recommend doing this conversion once the arrays are built.